# In OpenCart, how to pass information to a separate PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

In OpenCart 2.3.0.2, I'm trying to create a button in the Admin section that will appear on each order. Clicking this button should generate a .txt file containing certain information from that order (Customer shipping address, items ordered, etc.) in a specified folder on the server.

In a previous environment (osCommerce), I was able to achieve this by having that button be a form input, which would POST the order ID to another php script, which would use the order ID to fetch the required order information from the database and write a text file using fopen/fwrite/fclose. That script would also update the order status with a note saying the text file was created.

I guess what this boils down to is, is there a way in OpenCart to pass order information to a separate PHP script that is not natively part of the OpenCart structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a function in your controller, where you want to update order status and write all the order content in a file using fwrite.
2. Modify "admin/view/template/sale/order_info.tpl". You can add a button in HTML and then using jquery, add a onclick function.
3. In this function, you can send AJAX request to that controller. You can then receive file path of txt file in AJAX.
4. Then open this path from jquery using "Window.open(path);" function

Hope, it helps